# Log out of the jasig cas4.0 not logging out of google OAuth2.0 service

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, google-oauth, jasig

I am trying to implement OAuth services in jasig cas4.0. The login feature works correctly.

But when I logout of the cas session(http: //localhost:8080/cas/logout), and then again try to login using google OAuth service, it automatically logs me in without having to provide the username and passwords or permission.

Probably I am missing some configuration. Could somebody enlighten me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com). I'm the creator of the pac4j library as well.

When you call the CAS logout, it deletes the SSO session, but do not logout from OAuth providers you could use like Google or Facebook. Therefore you may still be authenticated by Google and can log in without entering any username and password, nor validating permissions.

Comment: Is not there a way, to end the OAuth session so that after trying to login again using the same OAuth provider, the user should at least have validate the permissions.?

Comment: The permissions validation is a tricky thing which really depends on the identity provider. I'm not sure you can change this behaviour with Google. For Google logout, maybe you could call a specific url from the CAS server or from the CAS logout page.